# How to push and remove item from an array on checked or unchecked of checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

when clicking on a checkbox and event.target.checked === true, in the following table, I am pushing the headerName and cell into an array, but I am unable to remove the item when event.target.checked === false, since I don't have the index of the added item. Any clue to solve this will be appreciated.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rgchvw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

**component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  public checkedItems = [];
  public tableHeaderNames = [
    "Header1",
    "Header2",
    "Header3",
    "Header4",
    "Header5"
  ];
  public roles = [
    "Role1",
    "Role2",
    "Role3",
    "Role4",
    "Role5",
    "Role6",
    "Role7"
  ];

  select(e, g) {
    if (e.target.checked === true) {
      let checkedObj = {
        headerName: g,
        cell: "test"
      };
      this.checkedItems.push(checkedObj);
    }
    console.log(this.checkedItems);
  }
}
```

**component.html**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th scope="col" *ngFor="let columnNames of tableHeaderNames"> 
     {{columnNames}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let role of roles">
      <td>{{ role }}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let roleColumn of tableHeaderNames; let i = index">
        <input (click)="select($event, roleColumn)" type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add another parameter for the `select($event, roleColumn)` to check against the `role` selected. As you need to check against both `headerName` and `roleNo` for cases when it's duplicate in row or column. Then add `findIndex` and `splice` for it.

You can make the changes like so

**html**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th scope="col" *ngFor="let columnNames of tableHeaderNames">{{columnNames}}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let role of roles">
      <td>{{ role }}</td>
      <td *ngFor="let roleColumn of tableHeaderNames">
        <input (click)="select($event, roleColumn, role)" type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**ts**

```
select(e, g, r) {
    if (e.target.checked === true) {
      let checkedObj = {
        roleNo: r,
        headerName: g,
        cell: "test"
      };
      this.checkedItems.push(checkedObj);
    }
    if (e.target.checked === false) {
      var index: number = this.checkedItems
                    .findIndex(x => x.roleNo === r && x.headerName === g);
      console.log(index);
      if (index > -1) {
        this.checkedItems.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
    console.log(this.checkedItems);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it using findIndex() and Splice()

```
else{
      let index = this.checkedItems.findIndex(
        item => item.headerName === g
      )
      this.checkedItems.splice(index, 1)
    }
```